# How do I clone A repo in B repo github actions if two repo is in same organization, not using PAT?

Tags: github, github-actions

In B repo, I have to clone other repos in same organization.

like, in B's action I want to clone A/C/D/E... and other repos dynamically.
I don't want to add each other private repo's PAT, because all repos are in same organization so I just want to use global organization secret.

I tried this:

```
      - name: Use environment variables
        if: github.event.pull_request.merged
        env:
          SERVICE_NAME: ${{ env.SERVICE_NAME }}
          ENVIRONMENT: ${{ env.ENVIRONMENT }}
          VERSION: ${{ env.VERSION }}
        run: |
          echo "Service name: $SERVICE_NAME"
          echo "Environment: $ENVIRONMENT"
          echo "Version: $VERSION"

      - name: checkout deploy-metadata
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: 'refs/heads/master'

      - name: clone deploying server
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: private-repo/${{ env.SERVICE_NAME }}
          ref: v${{ env.VERSION }}
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

but this doesn't work. How to clone other private repo in same organization without using each repo's PAT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was [discussed before](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/40792), and that thread references the documentation "[Checkout multiple repos (private)](https://github.com/actions/checkout#checkout-multiple-repos-private)"

> `${{ github.token }}` is scoped to the current repository, so if you want to checkout a different repository that is private you will need to provide your own [PAT](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line).

```yaml
- name: Checkout
  uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    path: main

- name: Checkout private tools
  uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    repository: my-org/my-private-tools
    token: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }} # `GH_PAT` is a secret that contains your PAT
    path: my-tools
```

So as long as you can provide a token of an account which has read access to each of those target repository, you should be able to clone them.

Comment: As I mentioned in the article, I need to make it possible without PAT.

Comment: @yacho From what I understand from your question, you do not want a PAT per repository. I propose using a unique token having access to all repositories.

Comment: So, Do I have to make a machine user?

Comment: @yacho one [SSH deploy key](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/managing-deploy-keys#deploy-keys) should be enough to access any repository within an organization (using SSH in the `actions/checkout`). No need to create any additional user/account.

Comment: So If I create another repo, then there may a need to associate that deploy key to new repository. I think it's kinda redundant to do.

Comment: @yacho Then a "[server-to-server token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/managing-deploy-keys#server-to-server-tokens)", through a GitHub App. That could be a way to *not* have to associate the token to each repository individually.

Comment: It's not free, so I think I gonna just make bot user for it. Thanks for the information!